# android play sound from sd-card

Tags: android, audio

I need to play sound from sd card. I have method that must do this but it's doesn't work.

When I use this method:

```
public class AudioPlayService extends Service

{
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
..............
    public void soundplay(String adr)
        {
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try
            {
                if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                {
                    mMediaPlayer.reset();
                }
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(adr);
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
            }
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener()
            {
                @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
            {
                mp.release();
                mp = null;
            }
        });
    }
```

Where String adr - it's absolute path to file on sd.

Then I call it:

```
AudioPlayService s = new AudioPlayService();
s.soundplay(iA.getSdDir() + "Files/Numbers/0.mp3");
```

and I get an err's:

```
12-09 13:04:13.829: E/MediaPlayer(16997): error (1, -2147483648)
12-09 13:04:13.829: E/MediaPlayer(16997): start called in state 0
12-09 13:04:13.829: E/MediaPlayer(16997): error (-38, 0)
12-09 13:04:13.839: E/MediaPlayer(16997): Error (-38,0)
```

Comment: make sure that your path is correct

Comment: Once you got answers, pls accept one of the answers which you feel is best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself tried your code:

Mine worked fine when i put just `"sdcard/1.mp3"`

You ensure that the path is right or not

```
s.soundplay(iA.getSdDir() + "Files/Numbers/0.mp3");
```

Note:
    If you are trying to make your method `soundplay` so as to stop previous audio and play the new audio file, then better would be `not` to perfom this inside that method

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

Place this in constructor.
Otherwise each time you invoke `s.soundplay(path)` you will hear previous audio plus the new audio. ie,Previous one will not be stopped

Answer (score 0):

`player.start()` put within try,catch block. Because if player not prepare your song ,still you are calling start method.start method is only called after  playback is ready,
means prepare is success.Another thing is that you have to release the media player when your player is no longer.Otherwise there is so many player objects are running in back ground.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, your `setDataSource()` or `Prepare()` is failing. So after the exception, `start()`is giving the error, since the player is not in Prepared state. Add print statements in the catch block to know what is the exception. And move `start()` into the try catch block.

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
try
{
  if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
  {
     mMediaPlayer.reset();
  }
  mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(adr);
  mMediaPlayer.prepare();
  mMediaPlayer.start();
} catch (IOException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```